# Is the term "farine intégrale" used for T150 or T180 flour?

Tags: choix-de-mot, alimentation

I read some contradictory statements.

http://www.archibald.bio/edito/12-classification-des-farines:

> - T150 : Farines Complètes
> - T180 : Farines Intégrales

https://lesbonnespoires.fr/diversifions-nos-informations/reflexions/farines-passez-a-la-version-complete/:

> On parle de farine blanche jusqu’à T65, puis de farine bis ou semi-complète (T80), de farine complète pour la T110 et de **farine intégrale (T150)**.

Is the term "farine intégrale" used for T180 or T150 flour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

À ma connaissance le T180 ne fait pas partie de la classification des farines de blé en France, T150 étant le plus élevé<sup>1</sup>. Peut-être certains meuniers utilisent-ils un taux d'extraction supérieur (T150 étant un taux d'extraction déjà supérieur à 90%) mais ça ne correspond pas à une norme française.
En tout état de cause la dénomination « intégrale » est une dénomination populaire qui réfère à la composition du grain. On trouve dans certaines marques la confusion entre farine complète (une partie du son est retiré) et farine intégrale (le son est conservé dans son intégralité).

Références non commerciales :
Article [farine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farine) de Wikipedia.
Article [farine de blé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farine_de_bl%C3%A9) de Wikipédia.
[Enquête sur les types de farines](https://www.franceagrimer.fr/Bibliotheque/INSTITUTIONNEL/CONSEILS-ET-COMITES-ET-COMMISSIONS/GRANDES-CULTURES/CEREALES/CONSEIL-SPECIALISE/2012/10-juillet/Enquete-sur-les-types-de-farine), document FranceAgriMer, p. 4, (2010).

Référence commerciale :
[Description d'un moulin](https://www.moulinsalmapro.com/fr/moulins-meules-pierre-granit-tamiseuse/moulins-avec-tamiseuse-integree.html) sur le site d'un fabricant.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>La farine de seigle va jusqu'à T170.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, great info!